# Css animation issue at the begging the of site loading

Tags: html, css

CSS animation issue at the begging of site loading.

I was trying to make a moving wave animation with CSS and SVG image but somehow it’s not working properly. I got an error in begging of site loading. You can easily notice a significant amount of time delay. I tried different browsers to test out and I came up with the same result all the time.
I am going to share my Html and CSS version of the code if anyone can help out I will be grateful.

```css
.ocean {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.wave {
  background: url(https://sq4dstaging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/wave-2.svg) repeat-x;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 198px;

  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   

}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) { 
  
  bottom: 25px;
  
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  opacity: 0;

   
  
}@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}
@keyframes swell {
  0%,
    100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
}
-webkit-@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}
-webkit-@keyframes swell {
  0%,
    100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -25px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ocean">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did you ran this code to get the error?

Comment: https://sq4dstaging.wpengine.com/news/